# Frontier output in LaTeX

Tags: tables, errors

I'm getting this error using code generated by Stata for frontier output:

```
LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

Here's the code:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{Regression table\label{tab1}}
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{log\_sorg\_out}\\
\midrule
Frontier            &                     \\
log\_sorg\_land       &       0.189\sym{***}\\
                    &      (4.37)         \\
\addlinespace
log\_labour          &       0.332\sym{**} \\
                    &      (3.23)         \\
\addlinespace
log\_oxen            &       0.221         \\
                    &      (1.45)         \\
\addlinespace
log\_capital         &    -0.00469         \\
                    &     (-0.10)         \\
\addlinespace
Constant            &       6.895\sym{***}\\
                    &      (5.46)         \\
\midrule
Sigma               &                     \\
Constant            &      -0.360\sym{***}\\
                    &     (-3.29)         \\
\midrule
Gamma               &                     \\
Constant            &      -0.263         \\
                    &     (-0.48)         \\
\midrule
Mu                  &                     \\
Constant            &       1.856         \\
                    &      (1.61)         \\
\midrule
Eta                 &                     \\
Constant            &     -0.0390         \\
                    &     (-0.67)         \\
\midrule
Observations        &         192         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) For the future, please always add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `\usepackage{dcolumn}` in your preamble, otherwise the column type `D` is not defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \centering
    \caption{Regression table}\label{tab1}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{1}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
        \toprule
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{log\_sorg\_out}\\
        \midrule
        Frontier            &          \\          
        log\_sorg\_land       &       0.189\sym{***}\\
        &      (4.37)         \\
        \addlinespace
        log\_labour          &       0.332\sym{**} \\
        &      (3.23)         \\
        \addlinespace
        log\_oxen            &       0.221         \\
        &      (1.45)         \\
        \addlinespace
        log\_capital         &    -0.00469         \\
        &     (-0.10)         \\
        \addlinespace
        Constant            &       6.895\sym{***}\\
        &      (5.46)         \\
        \midrule
        Sigma               &                     \\
        Constant            &      -0.360\sym{***}\\
        &     (-3.29)         \\
        \midrule
        Gamma               &                     \\
        Constant            &      -0.263         \\
        &     (-0.48)         \\
        \midrule
        Mu                  &                     \\
        Constant            &       1.856         \\
        &      (1.61)         \\
        \midrule
        Eta                 &                     \\
        Constant            &     -0.0390         \\
        &     (-0.67)         \\
        \midrule
        Observations        &         192         \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]